# Getting TLE in second last test case of sliding window (used queues)

Tags: python, algorithm, queue

Here's a problem from Leetcode that I've spent nearly 2 days on.

https://leetcode.com/problems/sliding-window-maximum/

I have been able to pass 59/61 test cases but am getting TLE on the 60th. Could you please suggest if I could tweak my program somewhere to pass all the test cases ?

The approach I've used is as follows:
slide is a list that consists of all the elements in the slide at a given time. As the slide slides one place to the right ,the element at the front is popped off, we'd have to check the max element each time. But the time can be saved if we check whether the max element really has been popped off. In case it is not the max element that has been popped off , we just have to compare the max element with the newly added element to the window and add that to the answer. However in case it is the max element indeed , we'd have to find the max element again.
With the above approach I could pass 59/61 cases.

Then I thought:

It is possible that the max element could be present at more than one place in the slide. So I initially created a set from all the elements currently in the slide and then found the max element , which might help to save time But that didn't help either. Here's the code that I've tried:

```
class Solution(object):
def maxSlidingWindow(self, nums, k):
    slide = list()
    answer = list()
    lennums = len(nums)-1
    if k==len(nums):
        answer.append(max(nums))
    else:
        
        for i in range(0,k):
            slide.append(nums[i])
        flag =1
        new=0
        while k<=lennums:
            
            if flag==1: #meaning the max eleemnt has been popped off. so we have to find the new max element again
                if slide[0]!=new:
                    new = max(slide)
                else:
                    new =new
                
                answer.append(new)#new has the value of max element in the slide
            else: #the element popped off was not the max element
                if new > slide[len(slide)-1]:
                    
                    answer.append(new)
                else:
                    answer.append(slide[len(slide)-1])
                    new = slide[len(slide)-1]
                
            
            
            popped = slide.pop(0)
            if popped==new :
                flag=1
            else :
                flag=0
                
            slide.append(nums[k])
            k = k+1
       
        slide.append(nums[len(nums)-1])
        answer.append(max(slide))
    return answer
```

Comment: for a long list this operation will become too much and take time

Comment: @sahasrara62 yep , could you please suggest any changes in it ?

Comment: Third approach [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sliding-window-maximum-maximum-of-all-subarrays-of-size-k) is O(n).

Comment: Not sure, but I think you can use a max-heap data structure.

Comment: @Aditi by using this approach you need to handle the case where list is in decreasing order, in that case your code is calcualting max again for all the slice. to improve it, just change that slice to a deque or balance tree (AVL i guess), if you change that into a deque then adding and removing will be O(1) operation and   if you max heapify that deque then it iwll be in O(1) time

Comment: @sahasrara62 yes right , thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a **deque** *(double-ended queue),* the structure which pops from/ pushes to either side with the same O(1) performance.

It's more handy to store in the deque indexes instead of elements since both are used during an array parsing.  Once you realized that, it becomes natural to approach this in different `que` way.

[Note] The similar idea has been discussed in many forum and credit should be shared to the "community".

**Algorithm**

It will be involved these steps:

Process the first k elements separately to initiate the deque.
Iterate over the array. At each step :

Clean the deque:

Keep only the indexes of elements from the current sliding window.
Remove indexes of all elements smaller than the current one, since they will not be the maximum ones.

Append the current element to the deque.
Append deque[0] to the output.
Return the output array.

```
# Implementation  - Leave as an exercise
# from collections import deque
```